# How to run a Powershell script from C# that references another script

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm trying to run a powershell script from my C# program like so:

```
var ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddScript(@"<full-path-to-script>.ps1").Invoke()
```

but it fails because within the script it references another script which gives me an error saying it's not found. However, running the script from the commandline works fine. I'm not sure I understand why this is not working from within C# but works in the commandline. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide more info? Like the specific part in your .ps1?

Comment: `AddScript` -> `AddCommand`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you have different working directories. How does the line look like inside `<full-path-to-script>.ps1` that includes the second script? It should use `$PSScriptRoot`.